# Angular 9 custom style/format HTML textarea

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, angular9

I am aiming to create a text area where users could style/format their text much like in the "StackOverflow" question creation box. Where users could either paste in already formatted text or create their own with the styling tools provided above the text area.

Needed functionalities:

- bullet points
- numbering
- text align
- text styling

  • bold

  • italic

  • underline

  • font size

  • font color

  • other fonts

The real question is: are there any packages for this or can this only be achieved by creating it from scratch and if that is the case is there any documentation or examples you could provide?

Comment: have a look at CKEditor https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/frameworks/angular.html

Comment: @vladkatz exactly what i was looking for. could you post that as answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always use [CKEditor](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/frameworks/angular.html). It's easy to integrate it into an Angular App.